# shell that protects against machine hanging due to bad process

Tags: performance, shell, ubuntu, system-administration

Is there a shell, or technique, that protects me against my entire machine hanging if a process goes haywire?

I'm using ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Try serverfault or superuser instead - they're more appropriate for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you restrict your resources with `limits` than you can even prevent fork bombs killing your machine.

Here's a nice tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-limiting-user-process.html

Answer (score 0):

I bought a multi-core CPU for that (it does not protect all cases in theory, but for all practical purposes it lets at least one core stay free almost always - to let your interactive "kill" command run.) :p